# derivatives of a vector of functions with respect to a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, vectors

Let $\vec W \in \mathbb R^3$. What is the general solution to:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{W}} \begin{pmatrix}
        f(\vec W) \\
        g(\vec W)
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I think that in the case where $f$ and $g$ are linear I could rewrite:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
        f(\vec W) \\
        g(\vec W)
        \end{pmatrix}
=A\cdot \vec W
$$
for some suitable matrix $A$ and then this would break down to:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{W}}A\cdot \vec W=A
$$

Is this correct? So my question really aims for the general case, i.e. when $f$ and $g$ are not necessarily linear.

It feels kind of wrong to take the derivatives along the rows given that $\vec W$ is a column-vector.

Comment: Be very careful, you can't "divide" by a a vector. What you can do is derive in the direction of a vector. You write this as $\frac{d}{dt} f(\vec a + t \vec W)$ (the derivative in the direction of $\vec W$ at the point $\vec a$)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. I wasn't trying to divide anything. I reformatted the equation to make it more clear.

Comment: How would you define $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial \overrightarrow{W}} \varphi$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found what I needed on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector) and it is actually quite simple:

$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_n}\\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Hence in my case this it would look like this:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{W}} \begin{pmatrix}
        f(\vec W) \\
        g(\vec W)
        \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f(\vec W)}{\partial W_1} & \frac{\partial f(\vec W)}{\partial W_2} &  \frac{\partial f(\vec W)}{\partial W_3}\\
\frac{\partial g(\vec W)}{\partial W_1} & \frac{\partial g(\vec W)}{\partial W_2} &  \frac{\partial g(\vec W)}{\partial W_3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The fact that the vector is a vector of functions doesn't add anything special to it...

Answer (score 1):

What you write is a (dangerous) abuse of notation. In dimensions superior to 1, the concept of derivative depends on the direction [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative)

In the particular case where it is linear, you can see that:

$\frac{d}{dt} f(\vec a + t \vec W) = \frac{d}{dt} (A \vec a + t A \vec w ) = A \vec w$

You can also look at the gradient (taking partial derivatives), which is probably more what you're after.

Comment: so I guess this is also a (dangerous ) abuse of notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector. Anyway, I think I've found what I needed...